# what does this mean for linkedin gem? undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, linkedin-api, omniauth

I get the following error now (didn't really change code, but started happening):

```
undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
```

I have this in my controller after authenticating with OmniAuth (and getting/storing the access token/secret

```
  7   def show 
  8     @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
  9     @client = LinkedIn::Client.new(ENV["LINKEDIN_KEY"], ENV["LINKEDIN_SECRET"]) 
 10     @client.authorize_from_access(@user.atoken, @user.asecret) 
 11     if @user == current_user 
 12       @client.profile 
 13     else 
 14       @client.profile(:id => @user.uid) 
 15     end 
 16   end
```

Driving me crazy trying to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you paste the complete stacktrace I can give a better solution, but basically, one of the parameters you're passing to one of the methods there, is nil.

Most probably on one of these two lines

```
@client = LinkedIn::Client.new(ENV["LINKEDIN_KEY"], ENV["LINKEDIN_SECRET"]) 
@client.authorize_from_access(@user.atoken, @user.asecret)
```

And if it "just" started happening, without a code change, I would bet my 2 cents that one of the ENV properties is returning nil

Comment: Right. Either that or one of the user properties is nil in the database.

Comment: thanks -- one thing I changed was @client to client...and I seem to not be having problems...ideas why?  I didn't make the change to ENV....

Comment: No idea why that might have fixed the problem. `@client` is an instance variable, while `client` is a local variable. Since you're writing to that variable in the method it doesn't *really* matter... I think.

Comment: I agree, it shouldn't...but it did....I *think* it's because we can't just access @client but need the profile method....